Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm after upgrading Strawberry Perl on Windows
I recently updated the Strawberry Perl on a Windows system from 5.32 to 5.40, and now I can't connect to my MariaDB database using DBI.
Here is the script:
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=mydb;host=localhost";
my $username = "root";
my $password = "MariaDBRootPassword";

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "$dsn",
    "$username",
    "$password",
    {
        PrintError => 0,
        RaiseError => 1
    }
);

$dbh->disconnect();

Every article I can find tells me that should still work.  (And it does still work on my Linux systems.)
The error I get is:

install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (you
may need to install the DBD::mysql module) (@INC entries checked:
C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib
C:/Strawberry/perl/lib) at (eval 6) line 3. Perhaps the DBD::mysql
perl module hasn't been fully installed, or perhaps the capitalisation
of 'mysql' isn't right. Available drivers: ADO, CSV, DBM, ExampleP,
File, Gofer, Mem, ODBC, Pg, Proxy, SQLite, Sponge.  at temp.pl line
12.

Sure enough, there is no "DBD/mysql.pm" in those @INC directories.  Various articles say that the "DBD::mysql" module is supposed to be included by default in Strawberry Perl.
I don't recall having to do anything to my previous Strawberry Perl installation to make it work.
Any help would be appreciated.
Update: As I suspected, the same happens when I try to connect to a MySQL database (as opposed to MariaDB).

Should be perl\vendor\lib\DBD\mysql.pm. I'll try installing the latest SP later.

I've found a backup of my previous Strawberry Perl 5.32 directory tree, and verified that there are "vendor\lib\DBD\mysql" files in it but not in 5.40.
So is this a bug in Strawberry Perl 5.40?  Or is the "DBD/mysql" support implemented  somehow differently in 5.40?

In the Release Notes for 5.40 I see "TODO: libmysql needs updates before DBD::mysql can be built".  In fact that is in the Release Notes for several of the last releases.
I think I'll just downgrade back to 5.32.

This report suggests DBD::MariaDB can be built with strawberry-5.38

Did you try to install it with cpan DBD::MariaDB ?

Yes I tried installing some DBD modules but all the builds failed with some error about not being able to find a mysql_config executable.
